# How to update multiple columns from within CASE in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, case

Is it possible to solve this without multiple CASE blocks?

Here's what I have so far: I've been working on this for a couple hours and can't figure out how to do it without repeating the CASE statement and setting one at a time. Here's what I've got:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET (status, mined_at) = CASE
                             WHEN id <= $1 AND status <> $2 AND status <> $3
                                 THEN ($2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                             WHEN id > $1
                                 THEN ($4, NULL)
                             ELSE (status, mined_at)
                         END
```

Any help is super appreciated.

Comment: i can see only one case, where its `repeated`? You want to get rid of that single case statement, or ?

Comment: Avoid the `ELSE`. Instead add a `WHERE` clause to keep transaction size down.

Comment: Sample data and expected result would be helpful to get you a solution

Comment: I *sincerely* hope that `$1` is not SQL injection.

Comment: Use an `ON UPDATE`  trigger and do the logic there.